# Ant design multiple select does not accept array as default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Title says what is the problem,
I have a compilation error where TS says :
Type string[] is not assignable to type 'string | number'
But the documentation says I can do This :

```js
                <Select
                    mode="multiple"
                    defaultValue={['ALL']}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                >
                    <Option value="ALL">Tout</Option>
                    {mediaGenres.map((mg: MediaGenre) => <Option key={mg.id} value={mg.id}>{mg.label}</Option>)}
                </Select>
```

When I check the type file for the select It is as this :

```js
export declare type SelectValue = string | string[] | number | number[] | LabeledValue | LabeledValue[];
export interface SelectProps<T = SelectValue> extends AbstractSelectProps {
    value?: T;
    defaultValue?: T;
```

So it must be accepted as string[]

I checked two versions of antd

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a sandbox and I get no type error.

Try this snippet out.

```
export default function App() {
  const { Option } = Select;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        defaultValue={["1", "2"]}
        onChange={(e: string[] | number[] | undefined) => {
          console.log(e);
        }}
      >
        <Option value="1">1</Option>
        <Option value="2">2</Option>
        <Option value="3">3</Option>
        <Option value="4">4</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If it does not works, you can compare your tsconfig.json with the config of  this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-solomon-kinkc

Comment: Plop ! I found what was going on. My onChange handler function was incorrectly typed.. Thanks this helped

Comment: In that case please type your onChange handler like this: (e: string[] | number[] | undefined)

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you assign your default value as a variable instead of creating it on the fly?

```
let defaultSelections = ["ALL"];
...
...
<Select
  mode="multiple"
  defaultValue={defaultSelections}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
  <Option value="ALL">Tout</Option>
  {mediaGenres.map((mg: MediaGenre) => <Option key={mg.id} value={mg.id}>{mg.label}</Option>)}
</Select>
```